# The appropriate firebase version to display message in foreground

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I want to display the notification instantly when a notify received. In this video [Angular 8 + Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ODE9l1c3ujY) I have seen about version 7.6.0 . In my case tt does display in foreground but I have to click to something to router it to the page again. Have anyone have experienced about this then please tell me. 
Here's my code that was done following to the video.

My messaging.service

```
export class MessagingService {
  tokenServer;
  currentMessage = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  constructor(private angularFireMessaging: AngularFireMessaging) {
    this.angularFireMessaging.messaging.subscribe(
      (_messaging) => {
        _messaging.onMessage = _messaging.onMessage.bind(_messaging);
        _messaging.onTokenRefresh = _messaging.onTokenRefresh.bind(_messaging);
      }
    );
  }

  requestPermission() {
    this.angularFireMessaging.requestToken.subscribe(
      (token) => {
        console.log(token);
        this.tokenServer = token;
      },
      (err) => {
        console.error('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
      }
    );
  }

  receiveMessage() {
    this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe(
      (payload) => {
        console.log("new message received. ", payload);
        this.currentMessage.next(payload);
      });
  }
}
```

My component.ts

```
  second: number = 7;
  tokenServer;
  message;
  constructor(private messagingService: MessagingService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.messagingService.requestPermission();
    //Gán token vào biến để sử dụng
    this.tokenServer = this.messagingService.tokenServer;
    this.messagingService.receiveMessage();
    this.message = this.messagingService.currentMessage;
  }
```

My html

```
<h1>
  {{ (message | async)?.notification.title }}
</h1>
<p>
  {{ (message | async)?.notification.body }}
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe the service methods inside the component and can get the result. As the service methods are asynchronous, your properties are getting undefined value because the observables have not completed yet.

Please find the code below:

```js
export class MessagingService {
  tokenServer;
  currentMessage = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  constructor(private angularFireMessaging: AngularFireMessaging) {
    this.angularFireMessaging.messaging.subscribe(
      (_messaging) => {
        _messaging.onMessage = _messaging.onMessage.bind(_messaging);
        _messaging.onTokenRefresh = _messaging.onTokenRefresh.bind(_messaging);
      }
    );
  }

  requestPermission() {
    this.angularFireMessaging.requestToken;
  }

  receiveMessage() {
    this.angularFireMessaging.messages;
  }


  second: number = 7;
  tokenServer;
  message;
  constructor(private messagingService: MessagingService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.messagingService.requestPermission().subscribe(
      (token) => {
        console.log(token);
        this.tokenServer = token;
      },
      (err) => {
        console.error('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
      }
    );

    this.messagingService.receiveMessage().subscribe(
      (payload) => {
        console.log("new message received. ", payload);
        this.currentMessage.next(payload);
      });
  }
```